# Independent color gradient for each facet in facet_wrap() + ggplot2()

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, gradient, facet-wrap

I'm struggling to plot a gradient color scale for each facet in `facet_wrap()` independently.
Data is too big to post it here but here is my code:

```
ggplot(stack, aes(hour, day)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = percent), colour = "white") + 
  facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'RdYlBu') +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = '#E5E6E1'),
    strip.text = element_text(face = 'bold')
  )
```

[image]

However, if I plot individually only one author, I get:

[image]

I just wanna plot each facet with its own gradient color scale, not share with the rest of the facets. Should be very simple, but I don't manage to do it. I tried adding `group = author` within `aes()` in `geom_tile()` and `ggplot()` but it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73578289/6171482

Answer (score 2):

After much research, I ended up using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139247/ggplot2-save-individual-facet-wrap-facets-as-separate-plot-objects) that uses `gridExtra`. I guess there is no easy way to do it using only `ggplot`.